# Root authentication with another root user

Tags: gnome, authentication, root, fedora-14, su

I have a PC at work running Fedora 14. For some reason, the IT guys do not give out the password for the root user, but instead, if needed they create a specific suXXX user with root permissions.

The entry in /etc/passwd looks like this:

```
su9705:XXXXPASSWORDXXX:0:0:Root My Name:/root:/bin/bash
```

As you can see it shares the same UID and GID as root, so anytime I need to do something with special permissions I can just type `'su su9705'`.

The problem is when I'm in the graphical environment, and some software (usually software installers, update managers) asks for the root password to perform certain operations. In that case I cannot use my su9705 password.

In the past I solved the problem by running su and changing the root password to something else, but I believe if IT finds this out they are going to kill me slowly.

I also added a line in /etc/sudoers to give my normal user user full permissions:

```
myNormalUser  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

However I'm still asked for authentication.

Are there any clean solutions to this? I would just like to be able to authenticate using my su9705 password instead of root in Gnome. Any ideas?

Comment: Start logging in to gnome as su9705, when the IT department finally realise what a ridiculous and dangerous thing they've implemented, they will relent, and if they don't, you win!

Comment: On a serious note - after the sudo change, when it asks for authentication, are you sure it's not just asking for your regular user's password now (which is how it would normally work).

Comment: With sudo you are supposed to use `myNormalUser`'s password.

Comment: You're asked for authentication *for your own account*. **This is a good thing**.

Comment: @Daniel: It only happens if the user is considered an "admin" by PolicyKit, which by default only recognizes uid=0 (and in Fedora, `unix-group:admin` IIRC). Otherwise, Polkit asks for the password of `root`.

Answer (score 1):

If Xprog is a GUI program which needs root perms, can you not initially invoke X by opening a terminal window and typing `su su9705 -c Xprog`? Then there's a good chance it won't prompt again for the password for `root`.